# How to Integrate Paytm Integration in React Native

Tags: react-native, paytm

I tried react-native-paytm package to integrate Paytm, it showed white screen with 404 Not Found error code. Here is my code -

```
const details = {
      mode: 'Stage', // 
      mid: "AstraD64640279792570",
      industryType: "Retail",
      website: "APPSTAGING",
      channel: "WAP",
      amount: 1, // String
      orderId:  "ORD3AXYBULQYUQFBBW", // String
      email: "astradairy@gmail.com", // String
      phone: "7777777777", // String
      custId: "2894",// String
      checksumhash:"DHYa9kmlmLT4tAGQC5e+95xLk+iqm8pIT7HapH1gCl+rVLFQJNb9Xfi+0eKgQ2KVuGYg5SR3Ss+BClnv9uAVmibWCl7KBiwVHK7E1ElSapA=", //From your server using PayTM Checksum Utility 
      callback: "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=ORD3AXYBULQYUQFBBW",
 };
 paytm.startPayment(details);
```

Comment: can you share the error what you are getting?

Comment: response: "{"ORDERID":"ORDL33LNM0HJL00O7E", "MID":"AstraD64640279792570", "TXNAMOUNT":"1.00", "CURRENCY":"INR", "STATUS":"TXN_FAILURE", "RESPCODE":"330", "RESPMSG":"Invalid checksum", "BANKTXNID":""}"
status: "Success"